# How do I include a module in spec_helper.rb?

Tags: rspec, paperclip

I am setting up testing for the paperclip gem and part of the instructions are this:

In spec_helper.rb, you'll need to require the matchers:

```
require "paperclip/matchers"
```

And include the module:

```
Spec::Runner.configure do |config|
  config.include Paperclip::Shoulda::Matchers
end
```

I am wondering if I should just paste:

```
Spec::Runner.configure do |config|
  config.include Paperclip::Shoulda::Matchers
end
```

into the spec_helper.rb file or if I should put it someone else and refer to it somehow in this file.

Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: The best place for `Spec::Runner.configure` is `spec_helper.rb`